# Formatting a number

Tags: php, number-formatting

I have a table with numbers like these:

```
19809.1
1982.0
1982.19
```

Its currency. Is there a function I can use to format these numbers like this?

```
19 809,10
1 982,00
1 982,19
```

Comment: Have a look at [`number_format()`](http://php.net/number_format).

Comment: @Blaine: I've always found `money_format()` more confusing than `number_format()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is quite easy with [`number_format`](http://php.net/number_format):

```
number_format(value, number_of_decimals, "decimal_separator", "thousand_separator")
```

Something like this:

```
echo number_format(19809.1, 2, ",", " ");
```

This tells the number to have 2 decimals, comma `,` as decimal separator and a whitespace   as thousand separator. Output will be:

```
19 809,10
```

Other examples:

```
echo number_format(19809.1, 0, "", ".");
> 19.809
> no decimal and . as thousand separator

echo number_format(19809.1, 3, ".", ",");
> 19,809.100
> 3 decimals, comma as thousand separator and dot as decimal separator
```

Comment: @ToKeN:  The `<kbd>` element / tag is meant to represent user input. It is not a means of making links look fancier or "styling" your posts.

Comment: @AmalMurali It doesn't matter, it looks beautiful

Answer (score 3):

[DOCUMENTATION](http://php.net/number_format)

```
<?php

$number = 1234.56;

// english notation (default)
$english_format_number = number_format($number);
// 1,235

// French notation
$nombre_format_francais = number_format($number, 2, ',', ' ');
// 1 234,56

$number = 1234.5678;

// english notation without thousands separator
$english_format_number = number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
// 1234.57

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

From https://www.php.net/manual/function.number-format.php

```
// notación francesa
$nombre_format_francais = number_format($number, 2, ',', ' ');
// 1 234,56
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for [`number_format`](https://www.php.net/number_format) function:

```
$val=array(19809.1, 1982.0, 1982.19);

foreach ($val as $v)
 echo number_format($v, 2, ',', ' ');
                     _  _   _    _
                     ^  ^   ^    ^
                value   |   |    |
        decimal positions   |    |
            decimal separator    |
               thousands separator
```

It returns:

```
19 809,10
1 982,00
1 982,19
```